# how to create live audio streaming between two android mobiles using socket programming..?

Tags: java, android, sockets, io, audio-streaming

I am trying to develop an android app that will allow audio streaming between two android mobiles kind of audio conferencing by using socket programming. 
what should i use for audio data transfer? i am using api 10

Answer (score 2):

if you want to link inside a LAN then there is hope; however, if you want to connect through the internet then forget about it, [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)s and [CGN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)s and the likes won't let you (well, unless you'll provide a third-party relay server for your app).

Comment: firstly i fetch the ip address of both mobiles and save it to the server every time the user runs the app. Like viber i am going to save the mobile number of user to server during registration. So the primary key will be mobile number and another tuple contains ip address of related mobile number.

Comment: actually, what i said is that you'll need a RELAY server, i.e. a server that will receive THE DATA STREAM from one phone and then send it to the other phone. Plus, using the server for the rendez-vous protocol requires MUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUCH more than just to remember the IP address of the two phones. Take a look [here](http://p2p-os.blogspot.com) if you want to know what you're dealing with. So, again, unless you can afford to pay for a server that will RELAY ALL THE DATA then just forget about it.